Run hybrid android app autotest on C# in docker via appium and change context
I'm trying to run autotests to check hybrid app but I get error.
Case:
C# tests run in Docker, with a physical device connected to the host that contains Docker. The Docker container can see the physical device via ADB, and the tests work. The problem occurs only when trying to switch context from the app to the WebView in my hybrid app to interact with a WebView element (click on the element). The tests (with WebView) work correctly if I run them on the host without Docker. The Chrome driver on the host and in Docker is the same.
Test error:
 -> error: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/313c0eef-312b-46d6-b8d5-45ea034bbfbc/context timed out after 60 seconds. (63.0s)


Appium log:
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Changed state to 'starting'
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Set chromedriver binary as: /chrome-linux64/chrome
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Killing any old chromedrivers, running: pkill -15 -f "/chrome-linux64/chrome.*--port=38147"
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m No old chromedrivers seem to exist
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Cleaning this device's adb forwarded port socket connections: 2383f958fc0d7ece
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;229m[ADB][0m List forwarding ports
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;229m[ADB][0m Running '/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -H 192.168.XX.XXX -P 5037 -s 2383f958fc0d7ece forward --list'
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Spawning chromedriver with: /chrome-linux64/chrome --port=38147 --adb-port=5037 --verbose
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Chromedriver exited unexpectedly with code 1, signal null
[38;5;98m[313c0eef][0m[38;5;39m[Chromedriver@4fd9][0m Changed state to 'stopped'

